# Guile make https request

Tags: scheme, gnu, guile

How do I make `https` requests using Guile? I make plain `http` requests using `web client`

```
(http-get "http://example.com" #:streaming? #t)
```

When I try to make `https` requests the same way, though, I get the

```
400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad news is that, by default, the web client package does not support HTTPS. If you check the source code of the open-socket-for-uri procedure it is clear that only "plain" HTTP is supported.

The good news is that you can specify the #:port parameter to http-get (and all of the http-* methods) to pass a TLS-encrypted I/O port. GnuTLS-Guile provides a mechanism to very easily create a TLS-encrypted socket as a Scheme I/O port.

Comment: It looks like the Web Client now supports TLS https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Web-Client.html